# Filter php array based on other array with different elements

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array `$items` as such:

```
[0] => Array (
  [itemid] => 8
  [name] => A
  [rating] => 9.5
)
[1] => Array (
  [itemid] => 41
  [name] => B
  [rating] => 9.5
)
```

and another array `$array` as such:

```
[0] => Array (
  [itemid] => 458
  [name] => C
  [rating] => 9.603 
)
[1] => Array (
  [itemid] => 460
  [name] => D
  [rating] => 9.603
)
[2] => Array (
  [itemid] => 8
  [name] => A
  [rating] => 9.523
)
[3] => Array (
  [itemid] => 41
  [name] => B
  [rating] => 9.2
)
```

What I would like to do is return the array `$array`, but with all the elements from `$items` filtered out. In this case it would return `$array`, but without [2] and [3].

I've tried with `array_diff()`, but the rating can change from one array to the other, so the elements in the one array are not always the same as in the other array.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Where is your code

Comment: There is none, I tried with array_diff, but since the elements differ, it isn't that straightforward.

Comment: You could try `array_udiff()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<?php

$arr1 = [];
$arr1[] = [ "itemid" => 8, "name" => "A", "rating" => 9.5 ];
$arr1[] = [ "itemid" => 41, "name" => "B", "rating" => 9.5 ];

$arr2 = [];
$arr2[] = [ "itemid" => 458, "name" => "C", "rating" => 9.603 ];
$arr2[] = [ "itemid" => 460, "name" => "D", "rating" => 9.603 ];
$arr2[] = [ "itemid" => 8, "name" => "A", "rating" => 9.523 ];
$arr2[] = [ "itemid" => 41, "name" => "B", "rating" => 9.2 ];


function compare_by_itemid($a, $b) {
    return $a['itemid'] - $b['itemid'];
}

var_dump(array_udiff($arr2,$arr1,'compare_by_itemid'));
```

Comment: As of PHP 7, you also can use `<=>` ([spaceship operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)) instead of `-` for comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the spaceship operator, did not know that :)

Answer (score 1):

You could first get the item ID values as keys of an $exclude associative array (like a set), and then iterate `$array` to perform the filter:

```
$exclude = array_column($items, "itemid", "itemid"); // create set
foreach($array as $row) {
    if (!isset($exclude[$row["itemid"]])) $result[] = $row;
}
```

The `$result` will have entries with item IDs that do not occur in `$items`.